# Why can't I connect to an .onion site on safari?

Tags: onion-routing, mac, safari

I have a question and I also have a doubt why I can't connect to deep web it loads then shows this:
[image]

And should I worry about maybe some malware could have been injected to my computer or accessed my files because I did this on safari without any VPN or proxy.

Comment: You're using `.onion.to` which isn't actually a Tor connection, just a normal web request.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not recommend using tor2web for visiting onion websites, use the tor browser which can be downloaded for Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux here: https://www.torproject.org/download/download

Using tor2rweb can result in huge security issues as it does not hide your ip address from the website.  I tried using it once and I could not get to any websites whatsoever with it.

If you go there in the tor browser and it still does not load, either the website was shut down or is temporarily closed, which on onion services does happen a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error message means that something is wrong with the server.

acording to this site:
https://www.toxigon.com/websites-like-tor2web-faster/

Answer (score 0):

It's far better to access Tor via the Tor browser itself rather than a third-party program. Although I have no experience in using Tor2web, you should use Tor directly if you want the least risk and the best experience.